# Proxy exec.Cmd Stdout / Stderr without losing TTY

Tags: go, colors, stdout, stderr, tty

I've got the following code that executes an arbitrary shell command and pipes the `stdout` and `stderr` to the terminal.:

```
c := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", cmd)
c.Stdin = os.Stdin
c.Stdout = os.Stdout
c.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

However, I need to process the output before I print it, so I've wrapped it with a proxy io.Writer interface:

```
type ProxyWriter struct {
    file   *os.File
}

func NewProxyWriter(file *os.File) *ProxyWriter {
    return &ProxyWriter{
        file: file,
    }
}

func (w *ProxyWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    // ... do something with bytes first
    fmt.Fprintf(w.file, "%s", string(p))
    return len(p), nil
}
```

So the original code is now:

```
c := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", cmd)
c.Stdin = os.Stdin
c.Stdout = NewProxyWriter(os.Stdout)
c.Stderr = NewProxyWriter(os.Stderr)
```

This works for the most part, however, `stdout` and `stderr` no longer seem to qualify as a TTY. Any previously styled or colored output is no longer styled or colored.

I've confirmed that this is not an issue of my `ProxyWriter` simply messing with the formatting by setting the command to the following, which outputs the colored text correctly.

```
c := exec.Command("echo", "\033[0;31mTEST\033[0m")
```

A more explicit test is:

```
c := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "if [ -t 1 ] ; then echo \"terminal\"; else echo \"not a terminal\"; fi")
```

Which outputs:

```
not a terminal
```

Is there anyway I can wrap the commands stdout / stderr without losing the TTY status?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
func (w *ProxyWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    // ... do something with bytes first
    fmt.Fprintf(w.file, "%s", string(p))
    return len(p), nil
}
```

To

```
func (w *ProxyWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return w.Write(p)
}
```

`fmt.Fprintf` have some logic to avoid terminal breaking.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `w.file.Write` rather than `w.Write`? The output is the same as `fmt.Fprintf` unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try? And what do you mean `qualify a TTY`? appear broken escape sequences?

Comment: Yes I tried using `return w.file.Write(p)`. What I mean by `qualify as a TTY` is that if I wrap os.Stdout in a io.Writer interface and set `Cmd.Stdout` to it, it will *not* qualify as terminal.

Comment: I understand what you mean `qualify as terminal`. Because it doesn't a *os.File. Maybe this can be your help? https://github.com/kr/pty

Answer (score 0):

You will need a full tty implementation to make an artificial stdout qualify as a terminal.  The library that mattn suggested seems like a good candidate.

However, another much simpler option may be available depending on the command you are trying to keep colorization for.  Most GNU utilities with color output such as `ls`, `grep`, and `dmesg` have a `--color` flag which can override the TTY detection.

For example:

```
$ ls --color=always

$ ls -lsh | grep --color=always drwx
```

I use this frequently to pipe colored dmesg output through less so that I can paginate it:

```
$ sudo dmesg --color=always | less -R
```

You can also do the opposite and disable color output:

```
ls --color=never
```